# How do I know if the Model Builder has updated.in ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

How do I know if the Modelbuilder has updated ?

So when I worked on Modelbuilder and then make some modified and added or subtracted tools. Sometimes you would forgot when you come back to it in a few days later and you have two same Model Builder and you don't know which one is the most recently ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your model is in a tbx file (so a toolbox not inside a geodatabase) you could check the modified data of this file using Windows Explorer.

Comment: That's the way I'd do it. System time stamps on the toolbox file. Unfortunately it will not tell you which model has been updated/saved; usually though you would be editing only one model at a time.